# How to use Kendo-grid into Angular-ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

How to produce `kendo-grid` with different data for each iteration of `ng-repeat` ?

HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="PricesPerGroup in AllGroups">
    <kendo-grid options="GridOptions"></kendo-grid>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$scope.GridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        data: {
            (data is current 'PricesPerGroup' - Should bring it from ng-repeat)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use helper function that would return proper config object:

```
<div ng-repeat="PricesPerGroup in AllGroups">
    <kendo-grid options="getGridOptions(PricesPerGroup)"></kendo-grid>
</div>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.getGridOptions = function(data) {
    return {
        dataSource: {
            data: data
        }
    };
};
```

Demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/eFaXA